# How can I get access to my personal documents on Amazon for my Kindle?

Tags: kindle, amazon

I used to sync my personal documents to my Kindle via Amazon website "Manage my Kindle". Unfortunately there has been an update to Amazon’s website and there, under Manage my Kindle, I simply cannot find any link to my **Personal documents**.

I can only see the purchases I made, but not the files I sent via the Kindle mail.
Any hint where to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found it buried under out-dated UX unfriendly and super stealthy drop-down menu! Special thanks goes to [Ed](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/38/ed-cottrell) who inspired me to look for a drop-down.

[image]

Highlighted in blue circle is the hidden menu (almost like an easter-egg). From there simply navigate to:

[image]

And they lived happily ever after...until Amazon updated their website AGAIN! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's in a dropdown, now.  Go to `Your Account > Manage Your Kindle` and you should see a screen like this:

[image]

The dropdown on the left (next to `View`) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes and no. I found it, but it looks nothing like the screen you showed. But you gave me sort of a hint :-)

Comment: Interesting. I'm glad I helped you along. Please consider posting your own answer to tell others how to solve the problem!